# Splitting a list by predicate

Tags: haskell, linked-list

I have written a function `splitAtPredicate` that splits the list at element `x` satisfying `p`, dropping `x` and returning a tuple.

```
-- | 'splitAtPredicate', applied to a predicate @p@ and a list @xs@,
-- splits the list at element @x@ satisfying @p@, dropping @x@.
splitAtPredicate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtPredicate p = splitAtPredicateAcc p []
  where
    splitAtPredicateAcc p left right@(x : xs')
      | null right = (left, right)
      | p x = (left, xs')
      | otherwise = splitAtPredicateAcc p (left ++ [x]) xs'
```

It works, but I'm new to Haskell, so I'm unsure how idiomatic and performant this is. In addition, I'm not too happy with the name `splitAtPredicateAcc`. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: from the description, `splitAtPredicate even [2]` and `splitAtPredicate even []` will both return the same result? also, it should be `right@ ~(x : xs')`. you say it works, but as written now, `splitAtPredicate even []` should cause error AFAICT. have you tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Haskell community :)

Haskellers like composition. Your logic is composed of 2 parts:

```hs
splitWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

```hs
toTuple :: [[a]] -> ([a], [a])
```

---

Let's address `splitWhen` first.

E.g. `splitWhen (== '2') "132342245"` should be `["13", "33", "", "45"]`.

To illustrate how it works:

```
initial state: (unconsumed input: "132332245", aggregator: [""])
step 1: (current input: '1', unconsumed input: "32342245", aggregator: ["1"])
step 2: (current input: '3', unconsumed input:  "2332245", aggregator: ["13"])
step 3: (current input: '2', unconsumed input:   "332245", aggregator: ["13",""])
step 4: (current input: '3', unconsumed input:    "32245", aggregator: ["13","3"])
step 5: (current input: '3', unconsumed input:     "2245", aggregator: ["13","33"])
step 5: (current input: '2', unconsumed input:      "245", aggregator: ["13","33", ""])
step 6: (current input: '2', unconsumed input:       "45", aggregator: ["13","33", "", ""])
step 7: (current input: '4', unconsumed input:        "5", aggregator: ["13","33", "", "4"])
step 8: (current input: '5', unconsumed input:         "", aggregator: ["13","33", "", "45"])
```

There are many ways to write this in Haskell, for example if we call the above logic `f`:

```hs
splitWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWhen p xs = f xs [] -- the initial aggregator
    where f [] agg = [agg]
          f (y : ys) agg = if p y
                           then agg : f ys [] -- we are ignoring the element here
                           else f ys (agg ++ [y]) -- put y into the aggregator
```

- Notice the pattern match `(y : ys)`, they are the current input and unconsumed input.
- Notice the recursive function call of `f`.

---

`toTuple` is trivial:

```hs
toTuple :: [[a]] -> ([a], [a])
toTuple [] = ([], [])
toTuple [xs] = (xs, [])
toTuple (xs:ys:_) = (xs, ys)
```

---

Finally the exiting part - function composition:

```hs
splitAtPredicate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtPredicate p = toTuple . splitWhen p
```

or if you are not yet comfortable with the pointfree style

```hs
splitAtPredicate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtPredicate p xs = toTuple . splitWhen p xs
```

Because Haskell's lazy nature, `splitAtPredicate` will stop when it finds the second element that satisfies the predicate, as we have enough data to construct the pair.

To put everything together:

```hs
splitWhen :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWhen p xs = f xs [] -- the initial aggregator
    where f [] agg = [agg]
          f (y : ys) agg = if p y
                           then agg : f ys [] -- we are ignoring the element here
                           else f ys (agg ++ [y]) -- put y into the aggregator

toTuple :: [[a]] -> ([a], [a])
toTuple [] = ([], [])
toTuple [xs] = (xs, [])
toTuple (xs:ys:_) = (xs, ys)

splitAtPredicate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtPredicate p = toTuple . splitWhen p
```

Hope that helps :) And again welcome to the Haskell world.

If you haven't done it already, checkout https://hoogle.haskell.org , you'll love it :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace accumulators by post-processing when possible.

```
splitAtPredicate :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAtPredicate p [] = ([], [])
splitAtPredicate p (x:xs)
  | p x = ([], xs)
  | otherwise = let (left, right) = splitAtPredicate p xs in (x:left, right)
```

Use existing library functions.

```
splitAtPredicate p xs = let (left, right) = break p xs in (left, drop 1 right)
```